# Flash Percentage Bar

Tags: flash

Do you know any open source option or tutorial for showing percentage bar flash(i will use for show user's feedback score) ? Example(The bar which is filled green): http://profil.gittigidiyor.com/usatr34&fb=ver&s_select=s

Answer (score 1):

while I don't know of any tutorials or open source component for this, this thing should be pretty easy to do.

create a movie clip with the bar graphics

add a movie clip inside that has the width at 100%

you grab a passed parameter (the percentage)

and some tweener class (there's a 100 of them)

some basic math where the `scaleX = percantage/100` and pass that to the tweener

BAM!!!, you're done - 30min MAX